# Mysql DATE_FORMAT and timing

Tags: mysql, date, format

i have a table called "reportinc" where i have to extract -it is VARCHAR field- items from 1 or some days past at 18:01 (time format as %H:%i) to today at 18:00.

I tried with this query

```
SELECT `ID incidente`, `Data/ora apertura`
FROM `reportinc`
WHERE `Data/ora apertura` 
BETWEEN 
(   
SELECT date_format( now( ) - INTERVAL 1
DAY , "%d/%m/%y at 18:01 " )
)
AND 
(
SELECT date_format( now( ) , "%d/%m/%y at 18:00 " )
```

I want to extract from yesterday at 18:01 to today 18:00.
But the results are form 00:00 yesterday to today. 
It dont consider 18:00 or 18_01 as valid time format.
How specify time into query?

MANY THANKS AGAIN

Comment: It is better to use DATETIME type instead of varchar.

Comment: Your date are turned into string values if you use varchar. Post your table structure so we can see if this is the case. If you can provide some sample data perhaps there is a work around.

Comment: This SQL FIDDLE demo shows the difference. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/205da/20 I have to run so other might help you further. Good luck.

Comment: @svrantonzo I have looked at your other questions and I wondering if  it would be easier to just open the CVS file with an import wizard in excel or ms access. And after importing the file you could then export it to MySQL, you could even keep the data in MS ACCESS it is also a database. When this is an one time event this would be something I would do.

Comment: You mention that you import the data from a CSV file created by an CMS. I assume that by CMS you mean content management system. Most CMS will have an database which stores the data. Is it possible to import the data directly from the CMS to to your MySQL database?

Answer (score 1):

The `Data/ora apertura`  field must be a DATETIME field, or you have to make a CAST.

Then you must do this:

```
SELECT `ID incidente`, `Data/ora apertura`
FROM `reportinc`
WHERE `Data/ora apertura` 
BETWEEN 
(   
    SELECT date_format( now( ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY , "%Y-%m-%d 18:01:00" )
)
AND 
(
    SELECT date_format( now( ) , "%Y-%m-%d 18:00:00" 
)
```

Between do not work as you expected when the field type is VARCHAR.

Comment: Depends. That field has already data that you can't delete? If it has, you must to do an script or a regex to convert the data to the correct format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) first, and the change the field type. If it hasn't, change the field type directly. But one thing you must take to account everytime, if you are storing a date the field must has date type.

Answer (score 0):

At first change the format from varchar to valid date format. varchar takes the value as string and you will have to use regex to bifurcate date and time. Better to go with former option.

Comment: THe date are imported from CSV from a CMS and cant import as DATE.

Comment: THe date are imported from CSV from a CMS and cant import as DATE.
Here the tab

ID incidente varchar(14)
Aperto da varchar(14)
Stato varchar(6)
Categoria varchar(17)
Area varchar(27)
Sottoarea varchar(36)
Titolo varchar(255)
Priorità varchar(11)
Data/ora apertura varchar(17)
Data/Ora risoluzione varchar(20)
Data/ora chiusura varchar(11)
Inizio Interruzione di servizio varchar(28)
Fine interruzione di servizio varchar(26)
Conteggio riassegnazioni varchar(24)


The **`Data/ora apertura`** fields contains something like:

31/07/2012 10.46
31/07/2012 10.47

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT added more specific date time format**

I ran in to the same problem the combination between time and date. Time is ignored therefore you get the results form the whole day.

Try PHP or another programming language to manipulate the MySQL out. Or try as I suggest to change the import method of the CSV file.

```
SELECT *,CAST((STR_TO_DATE(`Data/ora apertura`, '%d/%m/%Y %H.%i')) AS DATETIME) 
AS DATE_TIME 
FROM reportinc
WHERE (CAST((STR_TO_DATE(`Data/ora apertura`, '%d/%m/%Y %H.%i')) AS DATETIME))  >= ('2012-22-01 21:00');

SELECT *,CAST((STR_TO_DATE(`Data/ora apertura`, '%d/%m/%Y %H.%i')) AS DATETIME) 
AS DATE_TIME 
FROM reportinc
WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(`Data/ora apertura`, '%d/%m/%Y %H.%i'))  >= ('2012-22-01 21:00');
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE reportinc (
  `ID_incidente` int auto_increment primary key,
  `Data/ora apertura` varchar(30)
  );


INSERT INTO reportinc (`Data/ora apertura`) 
VALUES 
("31/07/2012 10.46"),
("31/07/2012 10.47"),
("22/01/2013 20.00"),
("23/01/2013 10.00");
```

[SQL FIDDLE demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ca13/74)
**---**

Try something like:

Using the cast function:

```
SELECT * FROM reportinc WHERE (CAST(`Data/ora apertura` AS DATETIME)) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 hour;
```

Using the str_to_date function:

```
   SELECT * FROM reportinc WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(`Data/ora apertura`,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 hour;
```

You are a bit unclear about the time range so I took 3 hours as a example. You can also use a specific date and time.

Using cast:

```
`SELECT * FROM reportinc WHERE (CAST(`Data/ora apertura` AS DATETIME)) >= ('2013-01-22 20:00:00');`
```

Using str_to_date

```
SELECT  * FROM reportinc WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(apertura, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))  >= ('2013-01-21 20:00:00');
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE reportinc (
  `ID_incidente` int auto_increment primary key,
  `Data/ora apertura` varchar(30),
  `Data/ora apertura1` datetime
  );


INSERT INTO reportinc ( `Data/ora apertura`, `Data/ora apertura1`) 
VALUES (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 day, NOW() - INTERVAL 1 day),
(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 hour, NOW() - INTERVAL 1 hour),
(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 hour, NOW() - INTERVAL 3 hour),
(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 hour, NOW() - INTERVAL 6 hour),
(NOW() - INTERVAL 9 hour, NOW() - INTERVAL 9 hour),
(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 year, NOW() - INTERVAL 1 year);
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/186d5/45)

B.T.W. My advices is to stop using slashes, spaces etc in column and table names.

I would appreciated it if you would accept answers that have helped you.

Comment: i think best way i sue this query

Comment: @svratonzo could you provide the table structure and some sample data? You can create the table structure with `SHOW CREATE TABLE reportinc;`.